# Prevent Celery Beat from running the same task

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have a scheduled celery running tasks every 30 seconds. I have one that runs as task daily, and another one that runs weekly on a user specified time and day of the week. It checks for the "start time" and the "next scheduled date". The next scheduled date does not update until the task is completed.

However, I want to know how to make sure that the celery beat is only running the task once. I see that right now, celery will run a certain task multiple times until that task's next scheduled date has been updated.

Answer (score 7):

In order to do that you need to implement some kind of "distributed lock", and easy an reliable approach to this issue is to use the django cache with memcached backend and set a "flag" in it when the task starts then just before it finish remove that flag. Other option is to use "redis" lock as "distributed lock". 
Example of using django cache memcached as backend:

```
@shared_task
def my_task(arg1, arg2, lock_expire=300):
    lock_key = 'my_task'
    acquire_lock = lambda: cache.add(lock_key, '1', lock_expire)
    release_lock = lambda: cache.delete(lock_key)

    if acquire_lock():
        try:
            # Execute your code here!
        except Exception:
            # error handling here
        finally:
            # release allow other task to execute
            release_lock()
    else:
        print("Other task is running, skipping")
```

The code above implements a "distributed lock" to ensure that only one task could run, no matter how many times you try to execute it again.
The lock can be acquired by only one task :), the other will just skip the "main block" and finish.
 Does it make sense to you?

Have fun!

Comment: I tried it but my tasks are still being duplicated. I also see this message from my celery log: "  WARNING/Worker-3] /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/cache/backends/base.py:224: CacheKeyWarning: Cache key contains characters that will cause errors if used with memcached: u':1:tasks object'
  CacheKeyWarning)"

Comment: what are you using as "key" ? It seems like you are trying to use the task itself. In that cases things can go wrong.
That is now good, you should use a "string" as I pointed out before, something like "my_only_one_task".
thanks!

Comment: Hi @martin-alderete , I am confused on what the string is supposed to be doing. What is the string supposed to associate with? Thanks!

Comment: hey @shizznetz, I have just read this comment. The string "lock_key" is supposed to be an identifier to your task based on your requirements. For example if you want to execute only one task for a given user at time, in that case you could use as lock_key as the following:

    lock_key = 'my_task:{0}'.format(user.id)

Hope you get the idea!
Thanks in advance!